# file not uploading or not append on ajax post response .net core

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm tired of trying a lot to solve the problem of uploading an image by popup form using ajax, it returns a null value " * validate required" every time I try to upload the image, and شll this code only works if you upload the image by view.cshtml and not by the popup modal.

This is a coding controller.cs:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PortfolioVm model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var catgportfolioModel = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Category_PortoflioVm>>(category_Portoflio.Get());
                ViewBag.catgportfolio = new SelectList(catgportfolioModel, "Id", "Category_Name");
                return Json(new { isValid = false, html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "Create", model) });
            }
            var files = Request.Form.Files;

            if (!files.Any())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Project_Photo", "Please select project image!");
                return Json(new { isValid = false, html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "Create", model) });
            }

            var poster = files.FirstOrDefault();

            if (!_allowedExtenstions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(poster.FileName).ToLower()))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Project_Photo", "Only .PNG, .JPG Images are allowed");
                return Json(new { isValid = false, html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "Create", model) });
            }

            if (poster.Length > maxAllowedPosterSize)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Project_Photo", "Image cannot br more than 1 MB!");
                return Json(new { isValid = false, html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "Create", model) });
            }

            using var datastream = new MemoryStream();

            await poster.CopyToAsync(datastream);

            model.Project_Photo = datastream.ToArray();

            var obj = mapper.Map<Portfolio>(model);
            portoflio.Create(obj);

            toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Portoflio item Created successfully");
            return Json(new { isValid = true, newUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard_Protoflio", new { Area = "Dashboards" }) });
        }
```

and this coding ajax :

```
jQueryAjaxPost = form => {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (res) {
                if (res.isValid) {
                    window.location.replace(res.newUrl);
                    $('#form-modal .modal-body').html('');
                    $('#form-modal .modal-title').html('');
                    $('#form-modal').modal('hide');
                }
                else
                    $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res.html);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
        //to prevent default form submit event
        return false;
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex)
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: how you write the popup and add the upload feature into the popup?

Comment: @TinyWang I wrote a code popup in the index view and open create by a button inside a index view, and set the upload feature into the popup by pass onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);" into the tag form.